# Save dialog box is opening on server side

Tags: jsp

I am writing web-based application using JSP. I have provided some links of songs to client. When client clicks on link then that file should be saved on client machine. But when client clicks on link the file save dialog box opens on server screen. What is need to be done so that it should open on client machine...?
My code snippet is as follows :

```
fis=new FileInputStream(path);
bis=new BufferedInputStream(newProgressMonitorInputStream(null,"Downloading File : "+fileName,fis));    
JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    if(chooser.getSelectedFile() != null)
    {
        String savePath=chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();

        modifiedPath=(savePath.replace('\\','/')).concat(".mp3");

        fos=new FileOutputStream(modifiedPath);
        bos=new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        int c;
        int i=1;
        try
        {
            while((c=bis.read())!=-1)
            {
                bos.write(c);
                i +=c;

            }
        }
```

}

file name is the file to be downloaded whereas savepath is the location on client m/c where file is to be saved.... fis,bis,bos,fos all are streams.
Please help..thnx in advance